# RAD Studio 10.4.2 Community Edition cannot make a new delphi project

Tags: delphi, installation, rad-studio

Submenu `File -> New` contains only `"Other..."` and `"Customize"` items.
How to correct this?

[image: RAD Menu]

[image: New items]

My OS is Windows 10.0.17763.107.

Old version is 10.2 with same problem.

Installed new version 10.4.2, in process of installation of Delphi Community, I have error at Roboto Font downloading:

> [403] Forbidden

I pinged this address of Getit found in the registry: https://getit-104.embarcadero.com

[image: ping getit address]

It is not responding! Ok, changing to getit.embarcadero.com, the result is negative.

Comment: Did you install earlier previous version of Rad Studio? Maybe with keygen? No offense. If yes, then check hosts file in c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ directory, there are rules that keygen makes and this address is redirected to localhost. I no, try to reinstall it.

Comment: Starter edition, not keygen. Illegal soft forbidden in my corp

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your Delphi installation hasn't finished properly. Either it was interrupted or Licence manager didn't manage to verify your Community licence properly.

You could try fixing your licence using Licence Manager that you can find inside Delphi folder. If my memory serves me correctly it is located withing BIN subfolder (don't have access to development machine at the moment to verify).

But if the installation proces itself is getting interrupted you might want to download ISO installation instead of Online installation. When installing latest version of Delphi I had to use ISO installation since Web installation kept loosing connection. I suspect my AV Software (ESET Internet Security) with integrated firewall might be the cause.

Comment: License is valid, resgistered=yes, couldn't find offline ISO

Comment: In that case try to opening Delphi and then going to Tools->Manage Platforms. It the installation was interrupted it is possible that none of the supported platforms is activated. As for the offline installer you can find more info at [Using the Offline Installer](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_the_Offline_Installer)

Comment: I'm trying many time, but I have same problem. Downloaded ISO with same problem, but contain key in registry "offline", if make it to "online" get message - fordbidden 403

Comment: I just noticed you are from Russia. Due to current geopolitical relations with Russia I'm guessing Embarcadero is forbidden to provide their own software to any Russian residents. So ?m guessing this might be the main cause for you not being able to activate your licence.

Comment: on my home computer, I successfully managed to install this version of delphi, at work connections go through a proxy server, perhaps the error is related to this, or blocking corporate IP addresses, but, I think.it is unlikely, but it is clear that this is due to the settings of the corporate network or DDOS attacks on this network, because admins regularly report this